# Bootstrap's Scrollspy not working at all

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, scrollspy

I need help setting the Bootstrap's Scrollspy. I followed the guidelines in the documentation and didn't work. Please help me find the solution to this problem

I am using data attributes in the body element and setting the position as relative
this is my HTML code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fascinate+Inline|Anton|Raleway:200|Megrim" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("https://image.ibb.co/i1Qu1R/Adobe_Stock_123146928.png") no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  top: 121px;
}
.active {
  color: black !important;
</style>

<nav id="main-nav" class="nav justify-content-end fixed-top">
  <!-- nav-fill nav-justified flex-column flex-md-row-->
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">marouane <span>rassili</span></a>
  <a href="#home" class="nav-link home active">
      <!-- flex-md-fill text-md-center"-->Home</a>
  <a href="#gallery" class="nav-link gallery">
      <!-- flex-md-fill text-md-center"-->Gallery</a>
  <a href="#about" class="nav-link about">
      <!-- flex-md-fill text-md-center"-->About</a>
  <a href="#contact" class="nav-link contact">
      <!-- flex-md-fill text-md-center"-->Contact</a>
</nav>


<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#main-nav">
<section id="home">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1>HOME</h1>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="gallery">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1>GALLERY</h1>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="about">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1>ABOUT ME</h1>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="contact">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1>CONTACT ME</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

(I am using Codepen)

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your markup following these recommendations:

- put `#main-nav` inside `body`
- add some content (or just height via CSS) to each section, in order to create a scrollable viewport.
- import Bootstrap 4 required JS files to run the scrollspy component logic.
- add the closing bracket to `.active` CSS rule
- create HTML markup using elements `html`, `head` and remember to close the `body` tag (modern browsers renders invalid HTML relatively fine, but it's encouraged to follow the markup rules and best practices to avoid further issues)

I've created a codepen with the changes implemented https://codepen.io/ZorphDark/pen/mBQwYZ

Comment: can you put it to work in my pen : https://codepen.io/mrassili/pen/LzzRxw